# axis stretches in graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot this thing

[image]

but for some reason my graph is weird:

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [xmin=0,
                xmax=80,
                ymin=0,
                ymax=27.5,
                xlabel={$t$},
                ylabel={$v$},
                grid=both,
                grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=black},
                major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=black},
                axis lines=middle,
                minor tick num=1,
                axis x line=bottom,
                axis y line=left,
                axis line style={-stealth},
                ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
                yticklabels={0,10,15,20,25},
                xticklabels={,10,20,30,40,50,60,70},
                ytick={0,10,12.5,15,17.5,20,22.5,25},
                xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75},
                xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
                ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}]
                
                \addplot[domain=0:80,red,line width=0.5mm,samples=500] {15*(1-e^(-x/5)) + 10};
                
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Do you have any idea why it happens?

Comment: I think the plot you aim for (the one in the image) has another function than that in you code. What exactly is your question here? If you don't want the large gap between *y* = 0 and *y* = 10, you should remove `ymin=0` from the axis options. Also, note that you set labels to the ticks that are different from their real values.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht, yeah I didn't like this strange looking grid with these large gaps. I wanted it to be exactly like shown in the photo. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not really specify what you don't like about your current solution, I will just try to copy the given plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
         width=40em, % (xmax - xmin) / scalingFactorBetweenXAndYAxis
         height=22.5em, % ymax - ymin
         xmin=0,
         xmax=80,
         ymin=7.5,
         ymax=30,
         xtick={0,10,...,70},
         minor xtick={5,15,...,75},
         ytick={10,15,...,25},
         minor ytick={10,12.5,...,27.5},
         grid=both,
         xlabel={$t$},
         ylabel={$v$},
         axis lines=middle,
         xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north east},
         ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north east},
      ]
         \addplot[domain=0:80,red,line width=0.5mm,samples=500] {15*(1-e^(-x/5)) + 10}; % whatever the correct function is
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]